# Оператор break в цикле for

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть csv файл, который содержит шапку, т.е. она забирает первые N строк (кол-во строк может быть разное), он не стандартизирован. Также есть последние N строк, которые имеют просто общую информацию по файлу, их я тоже отбрасываю во втором цикле.
Пишу цикл, который их пропускает пока не найдет названия столбцов.
Все работает, цикл завершаю командой break. При использовании команды break естественно, он мне не возвращает уже строку с заголовками.
Вопрос можно ли как продолжить парсить csv, сохранив корретку итератор на строке заголовка?
Или может есть какой-то другой способ выполнения пропуска строк.
Вот кусок кода.
Спасибо.

```
with open('Chapter1 B-A.csv', 'r', newline='') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';')
    for row in reader:
        if row[0] == '№ п/п':
            break
        else:
            continue
    for i, row in enumerate(reader):
        if row[0] == '':
            break
        else:
            print(row)
```

Comment: Если строка получена из итератора, то итератор уже перемещается на следующую строку. Откатить на строку выше не получится. Просто печатайте эту строку заголовка перед break, как будто вы уже во втором цикле.

Comment: Ну либо все строки сначала прочитать в список, потом ходить по ним в любую сторону, как вам нужно.

Comment: ``else: continue`` не имеет практического смысла, потому что это поведение по умолчанию. Если убрать, то совершенно ничего не изменится

Comment: Откройте файл, досчитайте до заголовка, закройте файл, откройте файл, пропустите нужное число строк, создайте `csv.reader`, читайте файл.

Answer (score -2):

Вамъ нужна машина состояній. Вотъ маленькій примѣръ. Программа пропускаетъ всё между буквами R и D, включая ихъ самихъ. Можно реализовать и гораздо болѣе сложную логику.

```
state = 0

for i in "ABRACADABRA":
    if state == 0:
        if i == "R":
            state = 1
        else:
            print(i)
    elif state == 1:
        if i == "D":
            state = 2
    else:
        print(i)
```

Comment: Сударь, хотѣлось бы видѣть Вашъ отвѣтъ въ современномъ, а не въ дореволюціонномъ форматѣ, ибо другіе господа могутъ и не понять Вашу логику измышленій чисто изъ-за формата :)

Comment: Тѣмъ хуже этимъ господамъ. Гдѣ-то я уже это слышалъ: будь прощѣ, и къ тебѣ потянутся люди. Вы знаете, а я не хочу, чтобъ ко мнѣ тянулись простыя люди. Я такихъ простыхъ на улицѣ вижу — за километръ обхожу. Кстати, дореформенная орѳографія — прекрасная лакмусовая бумажка. Я давно замѣтилъ: умныя люди никакъ на неё не реагируютъ. Въ томъ числѣ тѣ, кто обязанъ постоянно читать то, что я пишу. Спокойно, молча читаютъ, слова худого не говоря, хотя я ихъ къ этому не принуждаю, да и не смогъ бы, даже если бъ захотѣлъ, я не начальникъ. Болѣе того, если бы попросили они — я бы послушалъ. Но не просятъ!

Comment: Покамест не просят, потому что потешно читать, как боярский язык некогда. Вот 4500zenj вас попросил, а вы задвигаете телегу про лакмусовую бумажку.

Comment: Или вот [правка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1428633/revisions) была, которую вы откатили, а говорите молча читают, никак не реагируют. В целом, не стоит со своим самоваром в чужой монастырь ходить (или как там говорится).

Comment: От чего бы вам дальше не пойти и не постить ответы картинками с дореволюционным шрифтом?

Comment: `Болѣе того, если бы попросили они — я бы послушалъ` - в итоге не вижу, чтобы вы прислушивались к чужим словам, вы их просто игнорируете. Грош цена вашим словам. `Кстати, дореформенная орѳографія — прекрасная лакмусовая бумажка.` - по-моему ваша лакмусовая бумажка уже показала, что дореформенную орфографию тут не стоит использовать.

Comment: > в итоге не вижу, чтобы вы прислушивались к чужим словам, вы их просто игнорируете.

Прочитайте внимательно, что я написалъ. Рѣчь шла о людяхъ, съ которыми я работаю. Если бы попросили ОНИ — я бы послушалъ. Васъ я вижу въ первый и, надѣюсь, въ послѣдній разъ въ жизни.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, ну что ж, сочувствую людям, вынужденным вас терпеть. Меня вы тут увидите в последний раз разве что если перестанете тут появляться.

Comment: Да пересталъ я уже, успокойтесь! Зарегистрировался я здѣсь, лишь чтобы получить доступъ въ apl.chat и къ codegolf.stackexchange.com, а вы мнѣ всѣ чужды и безразличны. Засимъ разрѣшите откланяться.

Comment: @VadimTukaev, ну раз перестали, и мы все вам чужды и безразличны, то я думаю вы будете не против, если мы исправим написание ваших ответов, не так ли?

Comment: Не уловилъ взаимосвязи. Изъ того факта, что вы мнѣ безразличны, слѣдуетъ, что вы можете дѣлать что угодно съ собой или со своей собственностью, въ томъ числѣ интеллектуальной. А мои слова мнѣ не безразличны. Почему я долженъ позволять ихъ коверкать? Если мои сообщенія нарушаютъ какія-то правила — удалите ихъ. А новыхъ я писать не буду.